# Inner Product is Less than Zero

Tags: inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb R.$ Let $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4 \in V$ such that $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle < 0,$ for $i,j = 1, 2, 3, 4 i\neq j.$

Show that $u_1, u_2, u_3$ are linearly independent.

Please advise the ways to prove the result.

Comment: Inner product being zero would imply the vectors are perpendicular.  It has nothing to do with linear dependence or independence.

Comment: The statement "are independent so inner product $= 0$" is wrong. (To understand the geometry of the question think about the vectors pointing to the vertices of a tetrahedron centered at the origin.)

Answer (score 0):

Example: $V=\mathbb{R}^4$, $u_1=(1,0,0,0)$, $u_2=(-1,2,0,0)$, $u_3=(-1,-1,3,0)$, and $u_4=(-1,-1,-1,1)$.
This are all linearly independent because they generate $\mathbb{R}^4$. However, the inner products between each two are negative.

PS: the inner product is zero iff the vectors are orthogonal (that is the definition, but think of it geometrically). Also, a finite dimensional vector space has always a basis, and it has also an inner product, but that basis does not have to be an orthogonal basis. The example I gave was cooked so that the inner products are all negative, but imagine that they are all positive: $\{(1,0,0,0), (1,1,0,0), (1,1,1,0), (1,1,1,1)\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors, and non is orthogonal to another.

Comment: Just to prove that all four don’t need to be linearly independent, consider in $\mathbb R^3$ the vectors $$(1,-1,0), (1,2,3),(1,2,-3),(-1,0,0).$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, that is a good example. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. can you please provide the proof also.